# How to pass arguments to read-function of a collectd perl-plugin?

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures, collectd

I'm trying to implement a collectd-plugin, which is supposed to report data for multiple instances of a server-process on the same machine.

My TYPE_CONFIG-function is fine -- it gets each configuration-item and parses it.

What I'm struggling with is the TYPE_READ-function -- I'd like each invocation of the reader to report only on *one* of the server-instances so that, should an invocation fail for one instance, the rate, with which collectd invokes the method for *other* instances, is not affected.

So I tried to register multiple TYPE_READ methods from inside the TYPE_CONFIG-method.

Unfortunately, collectd does not pass any arguments to the read-method... One alternative is to build a list of instances in config, register only one reader, and then loop through the list inside it -- this works but has the drawback mentioned above: should one instance fail to report its stats, the daemon will lower the inquiry rate for all instances.

The other alternative *may* be to use Perl's anonymous functions -- but I'm not sure, how. The below does not work:

```
    my @data = [$m_instance, $connection];
    plugin_register(TYPE_READ, "foo", sub { return mongo_read(@data); });
```

Collectd rejects such a call with: `Collectd::plugin_register: Invalid data`.

Is there, perhaps, some easy way to create such a function in a way acceptable to plugin_register?

Answer (score 0):

Square backets [ ] create an array ref, not an array.

```
my @data = ($m_instance, $connection);
```

or

```
my $data = [$m_instance, $connection];
plugin_register(TYPE_READ, "foo", sub { return mongo_read($data); });
```

And then deal with a reference to an array in your mongo_read() sub.